# Random number matrix within a specified range in Python

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to generate a random number matrix within a specified range, say `(0,1)`.

```
import numpy as np
A=np.random.random((3, 3))
print("A =",[A])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[numpy.random.uniform](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.uniform.html) can receive `low`, `high` and `size` parameters

Range 0-1 is the default

```
A = np.random.uniform(size=(3, 3))
print("A =", [A])
```

Output

```
A = [array([[0.76679099, 0.57459256, 0.07952816],
            [0.02736909, 0.05905416, 0.09909474],
            [0.08690106, 0.81983883, 0.18740471]])]
```

If you want another range specify it with parameters

```
A = np.random.uniform(0.2, 0.3, (3, 3))
print("A =", [A])
```

Output

```
A = [array([[0.20548205, 0.25373507, 0.28957419],
            [0.20496673, 0.27004844, 0.28633947],
            [0.22325187, 0.26327935, 0.24548129]])]
```

Answer (score 1):

you will be use it generate range [0, 1)

```
np.random.rand(d0, d1, ..., dn)
```

Create an array of the given shape and populate it with random samples from a uniform distribution over [0, 1).

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.rand.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use Numpy's built-in rand method, which generates a matrix with random numbers with a uniform distribution over [0, 1).

```
A = np.random.rand(3, 3)
```

Comment: What if I wish to change the range, say between ```(0.2,0.3)```?